# JSON Array Export to CSV in PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach, fputcsv

I'm trying to export to csv, a JSON with the following format:

```
$json_file2{
            "errors":
                    {
                    "code":0,
                    "text":""
                    },
            "results":
                    {
                    "resultado":
                    [
                        {
                        "referencia":"00000",
                        "cantidad":"24",
                        "cantidad_proveedor":null,
                        "delivery_time":"delivery time 2 days"
                        },
                        {
                        "referencia":"00001",
                        "cantidad":"24",
                        "cantidad_proveedor":"48",
                        "delivery_time":""
                        },
                        {
                        "referencia":"00098_1",
                        "cantidad":"96",
                        "cantidad_proveedor":null,
                        "delivery_time":"delivery time 4 days"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I need to export to csv

```
"referencia":"00000",
"cantidad":"24",
"cantidad_proveedor":null,
"delivery_time":"delivery time 2 days"
```

in this format:

```
"00000","24",null,"delivery time 2 days"
"00001","24","48",""
"00098_1","96",null,"delivery time 4 days"
......
```

I try to do as I am learning

```
$decoded = json_decode($json_file2);
$comments = $decoded->data[0]->results->resultado;
$fp = fopen('stock2.csv', 'w');
foreach($comments as $comment){
   fputcsv($fp,$comment);
}
```

but always it gives me error foreach:
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Where am I doing wrong?
Tanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no data array field** in $json_file2.
You have to use **$decoded->results->resultado** instead. And cast **$comment** as **array** as Brian says.

Final code look like this:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json_file2);
$comments = $decoded->results->resultado;
$fp = fopen('stock2.csv', 'w');
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    fputcsv($fp, (array)$comment);
}
```

With that change you will get something like that:

```
00000,24,,"delivery time 2 days"
00001,24,48,
00098_1,96,,"delivery time 4 days"
```

Maybe you should write **your own fputcsv** function to achive the result you wish, with null and numbers with quotes.

Comment: PERFECT Ujin ! THANKS!
I can not give you a positive, not having enough reputation :(

Comment: @Juanjo You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of this item. This will give the user +15 reputation and I believe will give you +2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in an array to fputcsv.  Use this code:

fputcsv($fp,(array)$comment);

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()